# Passing information to template from multiple tables with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have to pass multiple tables info with Laravel. I always do this:

```
public function get_view(){
        $myinfo = Table::where('id',Auth::user()->id)->get();
        return view('auth.view')->with('myinfo',$myinfo);
    }
```

I need to pass info from other tables. The function "with" only allows me to pass a single table. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:

```
return view('auth.view')->with('myinfo', $myinfo)->with('anotherVar', $anotherVar);
```

Option 2:

```
$var1, $var2;
return view('auth.view', compact('var1', 'var2'));
```

Which translates to (option 3):

```
$var1, $var2;
return view('auth.view', ['var1' => $var1, 'var2' => $var2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an array with multiple tables as second parameter:

```
public function get_view() {
    $myinfo = Table::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
    return view('auth.view', [
        'myinfo1' => $table1,
        'myinfo2' => $table2,
    ]);
}
```

Also, you could use mutiple `with()`

Answer (score 1):

There is a method compact. Your example:

```
public function get_view(){
    $myinfo = Table::where('id',Auth::user()->id)->get();
    $myinfo2 = ...
    return view('auth.view', compact('myinfo', 'myinfo2'));
}
```